# Modifying database using LINQ to SQL in C# makes the database inaccessible in SQL Management Studio

Tags: linq-to-sql, ssms

Using SQL Server 2008 Express, I attach the Northwind database in SQL Server Management Studio, and everything works fine.

I then disconnect the server, shut down SQL Server Management Studio, and modify the Northwind database using the following LINQ to SQL C# code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace LinqConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Northwnd db = new Northwnd(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
                Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\northwnd.mdf");

            Customer testCust = new Customer();
            testCust.CompanyName = "Dummy"; testCust.CustomerID = "DE1";
            db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(testCust);

            db.SubmitChanges();
            db.Dispose();            

        }
    }
}
```

This executes without errors. When I re-open Management Studio and select the Northwind database, I get a 'database is not accessible' error message, and can't view any of Northwind's tables.

Any idea why running this LINQ code would prevent Management Studio from subsequently accessing the database?

Thanks

---

update:

The `Northwnd` class was generated automatically from sqlmetal.exe, so it does the following to connect to the MDF file when the `Northwnd()` constructor is called:

```
public Northwnd(string connection) : (connection, mappingSource)
{
    OnCreated();
}
```

where `OnCreated()` does nothing, the base class is `System.Data.Linq.DataContext`, and 'mappingSource' is:

```
private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us what exactly you do in your `Northwnd` class??

I think it's odd (to say the least - if not outright dangerous) that you seem to have `Northwind` attached to your SQL Server Express instance (so you can access it in SQL Server Management Studio), and at the same time, your `Northwnd` class appears to be accessing that MDF file (while it's attached to SQL Server Express) **directly**.......

I would try to use the "normal" connection strings if I could:

```
server=.\SQLExpress;Database=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

while a database is attached to the SQL Server Express instance......

Comment: Thanks marc_s. I generated the `Northwnd` class directly from the database using Microsoft's sqlmetal.exe generator. It's thousands of lines, but I will update the question with the essentials of what it does to connect. Thanks especially for pointing out the dangerous behavior. I thought that closing SQL Server Management Studio would disconnect `Northwind` from my SQL Server Express Instance, which of course it does not. It seems to behave fine if I just make sure to detach `Northwind` before accessing the MDF file with my class directly.